# Calculating normal vector distance between two surfaces using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, surface, calculate-values

I have two surfaces mapped out from seismic data, imported as x,y,z datasets in ArcMap and then converted to rasters using the point to raster tool. These surfaces are rugose (seafloor and an underlying horizon), and I want to know if there is a way to calculate the shortest distance from the lower horizon to the upper?

An approximation of this would be to calculate the path that is normal to the lower surface (as shown in B), rather than just the vertical distance (as shown in A), as would be calculated in an isopach. Is there a way to do this in Arc and save the calculated values as a surface / contour set?

[image: Isopach calculation (vertical distance)][image: Normal vector distance - normal to lower surface]